# iWork '09 Keeps asking to be Registered

Tags: pages, remote-desktop, iwork, keynote, numbers

I'm a teacher in a classroom with 8, 9 10 and 11 year olds who each have a macbook or a macbook pro. Fun job. We have a standard 10.6.6 image with iWork '09 (4.03).

In previous images, iWork would ask to be registered thrice (it changed to 'Never Register' on the third time), and then stop bugging you; but now for some reason it won't stop asking us to register. It's a real hassle. I've repaired disk permissions, but that doesn't fix it. Any ideas how to stop it from asking us to register? Bonus points if I can roll it out using a terminal script via. remote desktop.

Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this via google [Disable iWork registration nag screen](http://angrydome.org/post/441784022/disable-iwork-registration-nag-screen).

```
defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.iWork09 RegistrationHasBeenSent true
```

I have no idea if this will work for you. I wanted to point this out in case you hadn't tried it.

This blog was the first result in google from searching for `iwork disable reg`. If it doesn't work, you might see if there are more results that might help or a slightly different search that might provide something meaningful. In any event, good luck. I hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error: 2011-03-11 15:06:12.295 defaults[1155:903] Could not write domain com.apple.iWork09; exiting - I'll have a little Google. I've just used the Apple SE for so long it's my first port of call, but you're right, google is always there too.

Comment: perhaps try `defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iWork09 RegistrationHasBeenSent true` (e.g. in your user directory instead).

Comment: Great - that last comment works, but not via remote desktop for some reason. Thankyou!

Comment: The link is dead. On a freshly installed `iWork '09` the `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iWork09` is empty and changing it doesn't stop the repeated registration window.

Answer (score 3):

To change the global settings (`/Library/...`, not `~/Library/...`), you must run the command with sudo:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.iWork09 RegistrationHasBeenSent true
```

Answer (score 0):

The setting is a per user one. Every different user on a given Mac
may register his E-mail.

You can force the registration to be considered as sent with:

```
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iWork09 RegistrationHasBeenSent true
```